# How to handle Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off

Tags: wget, download

I was mirroring a site but something happened and wget died. So I had to run it again but I realized that `Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.` was repeated so often in the output so I suspect wget is downloading already downloaded files what should I do?

**Here is my original command:**

```
wget -m -nc -p -E -k -np -e robots=off www.site.com
```

**Here is my resuming command:**

```
wget -m -c -p -E -k -np -e robots=off www.site.com
```

Answer (score 2):

`-nc` is `--no-clobber` while, `-c` is `--continue`. Is this what you intended?

However, it seems like the server doesn't support the `If-Modified-Since` header. That makes it harder for Wget to resume downloading. With the `-c` option, wget will still attempt to check if the file has been completely downloaded, but that again depends on the server's ability to handle `Range:` headers

We could help you more if atleast a part of Wget's output was shared. Preferably with the `--debug` switch enabled

Comment: But am I using the right options for continuing the interrupted mirror? I don't care if a few files will become corrupt

Comment: Seems like it, yes